# How to make readable alias of a file descriptor

Tags: bash, shell

I know how to make alias of a file descriptor

```
exec 3>&1  1> /dev/null 
echo "hello world" >&3
```

but this is not readable. Is there any way to make it readable (means instead of >&3 can I write LOG or INFO or DEBUG) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use parameters to store the file descriptor to use.

```
exec 3>&1 1>/dev/null
LOG=3
echo "hello world" >&$LOG
```

You cannot store the `>&` part in a parameter, because that is shell syntax, not data. You can, however, write a function which will output its argument(s) to a specific file descriptor.

```
LOG () {
    echo "$@" >&3
}
LOG "hello world"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you write `&1` you refer to standard *output*, which is used for, well, output. You also used `>` for redirection which is used for output.

If you care about *input*, you could use for example standard input by referring to `&0`. In that case you also should use `<` for input.

For example:

```
exec 3<&0
```

For more information type `man bash` and look for the section on redirection.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you want fd 3.
In my solution I show how you can mix fd1 and fd3:

```
function opendebug {
   exec 3>&1 1> /dev/null
}

function mylog {
   level=$1
   shift
   printf "(fd 1) %s: %s\n" "${level}" "$*"
   printf "(fd 3) %s: %s\n" "${level}" "$*" >&3
}

function logerror {
   if [ ${loglevel} -ge 1 ]; then
      mylog "ERROR" "$*"
   fi
}

function loginfo {
   if [ ${loglevel} -ge 3 ]; then
      mylog "INFO" "$*"
   fi
}

function logdebug {
   if [ ${loglevel} -ge 5 ]; then
      mylog "DEBUG" "$*"
   fi
}

export loglevel=3

logerror "Line with error"
loginfo  "Line with info"
logdebug "Line with debug" # will be suppressed

echo Open debug
opendebug
logerror "Line with error"
loginfo  "Line with info"
logdebug "Line with debug" # will be suppressed
```

Output:

```
(fd 1) ERROR: Line with error
(fd 1) INFO: Line with info
Open debug
(fd 3) ERROR: Line with error
(fd 3) INFO: Line with info
```